# Can't display data from strapi with next js

Tags: next.js, fetch-api, strapi

I'm trying to display a collection of articles in a web page.

I can't figure out how to fetch the data from strapi in my next js app.

I manage to get the json but the attributes property doesn't work.

```
    data : [object Object]
{
  data: [ { id: 1, attributes: [Object] } ],
  meta: { pagination: { page: 1, pageSize: 25, pageCount: 1, total: 1 } }
}
```

I create a utils to handle the API and 2 components to fetch the data and assign them to the component "ArticleListItem"

```
// api.js

const baseUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_URL

async function fetcher(path, options = {}) {
    let url
    if (!options) {
        url = `${baseUrl}/${path}/${params}`
        console.log(url)
    } else {
        url = `${baseUrl}/${path}`
        console.log(url)
    }
    const response = await fetch(`${url}`)
    console.log(response)
    const data = await response.json()
    console.log(data)
    return data;
}

export { baseUrl, fetcher }
```

```
// articles.js

import Layout from '../components/Layout'
import ArticleListItems from '../components/ArticleListItems'
import { fetcher } from '../lib/api'

const ArticlesList = ({ articles }) => {
    return (
        <Layout>
            <ArticleListItems articles={ articles }/>
        </Layout>
    )
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
    const articles = await fetcher('articles')
    return {
      props: {
        articles
      }
    }
  }

export default ArticlesList
```

```
// ArticleListItems.jsx

const ArticlesListItems = ({ articles }) => {
    console.log(articles)
    return (
        <div className="bg-white">
            {articles && articles.length
                ? articles.map((article) => (
                    <li key={article.id}>
                        <h1 className="text-sm text-gray-700">{article.attributes.title}</h1>
                    </li>
                ))
                : "no articles"}
        </div>
    )
}

export default ArticlesListItems
```

[image]

Here is a test with Hoppscotch

[image]

Comment: Did you check permissions in strapi admin panel?

Comment: Please share the `NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_URL` env variable and possibly as well the browser's console for any logs.